# What is meaning of margin in constraint set connect

Tags: android, view, android-constraintlayout

The official documentation of the constraint set connect says: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintSet.html#connect(int, int, int, int, int)

```
void connect (int startID, 
                int startSide, 
                int endID, 
                int endSide, 
                int margin)
```

the margin to constrain (margin must be postive)

For my understanding if I want to connect two views with the left to right of then this margin is left margin.

//left to right of

```
constraintset.connect(textView.id,ConstraintSet.LEFT,previousTextViewId,ConstraintSet.RIGHT,10)
```

then 10 is the left margin. Am I right? I have implemented this concept but no margin is set even no right or left. What am I missing?

Comment: See updated answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Update:** It looks like this issue has been fixed, but I haven't checked it out. See the [bug report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62154545).

---

---

Your understanding is also how I understand things. Here is a quick way to check how things are working.

In the layout below, the top left corner of `textRight` lines up with the lower right corner of `textLeft`. When `MainActivity` runs, `textRight` should move 1,000px down and 1,000px to the right. It moves 1,000 px down but does not move to the right at all.

I believe that this is an outstanding issue. See this [issue report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62154545).

I don't know a work-around and I am surprised that this could even be a bug. I am willing to stand corrected if anyone sees the error.

**two_text_views.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textLeft"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="TextView1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textRight"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView2"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textLeft"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textLeft"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

**MainActivity.java**

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ConstraintLayout layout;
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.two_text_views);

        ConstraintSet constraints = new ConstraintSet();
        constraints.clone(layout);
        constraints.connect(R.id.textRight, ConstraintSet.LEFT, R.id.textLeft, ConstraintSet.RIGHT, 1000);
        constraints.connect(R.id.textRight, ConstraintSet.TOP, R.id.textLeft, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, 1000);
        constraints.applyTo(layout);
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT** So, here is a fix. Use `ConstraintSet.START` and `ConstraintSet.END` instead of `ConstraintSet.LEFT` and `ConstraintSet.RIGHT`. I just tried it and it works OK. I can't say why left and right don't work.

Comment: This one almost killed me!!  Thanks for the edit!  END vs RIGHT...unbelievable.